# How to add inner shadow to text?

Tags: css, saas

Our designer is going a bit crazy these days close to Christmas and he asked me to add some inner shadow to some text.

This is how it should look

[image]

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
.text-shadow {
  text-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.35)
}
```

It is not working at all :(

We normally use Sketch for all the design stuff, but I'm not sure how the option inner shadow can be applied to the numbers since it is not possible to add inset shadows to any text.

Comment: [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NeqCC/)

Comment: You want to use Software as a Service (the `saas` tag) to accomplish this?

Comment: you forget to write px for the third parametre : next to 7 look at your code you write it without px !!

Comment: I don't really see how the other question answers this one, actually. This one is asking for the shadow inside the lettering.